# PayPal POST payment vars not present on mobile checkout

Tags: post, mobile, paypal

I'm using the JS Buy It Now button for payments, like this:

```
<script src="paypal-button.min.js?merchant=qwertyseller@gmail.com"
                data-env="sandbox"
                data-button="buynow"
                data-name="Product"
                data-amount="1"
                data-currency="GBP"
                data-shipping="0"
                data-tax="0"
                data-callback="http://1.1.1.1/paypal/paypalipn.php"
                data-return="http://1.1.1.1/paypalreturn.php"
                data-cbt="Click here to finish!"
                data-no_note="1"
                data-no_shipping="1"
                data-rm="2">
</script>
```

When I reach `http://1.1.1.1/paypalreturn.php` on Mobile Safari, $_REQUEST is empty. That is, I don't get any payment-related form variables back, even tough I've set `data-rm` to 2. It works as expected on desktop browsers. I can reproduce this by setting my UA to that of the iPhone. Is this a bug? Note that I am still testing on the Sandbox, so perhaps it only happens there.

Apparently I can get the same info as what is posted to my return page by using Auto Return and PDT, can I use that instead?

Comment: This is a serious bug in the paypal sandbox. Yet to find out if it exists in the live site yet.

Comment: Related Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22835265/successful-paypal-payment-not-posting-back-data-but-only-for-mobile-checkout