# Successful PayPal payment not posting back data, but only for mobile checkout

Tags: mobile, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have seen this question asked a few times, but without any successful answers.

We have a fully functioning desktop checkout utilising PayPal as a payment option. After successfully completing an order, the customer is returned back to our website return_url using the POST return method, as indicated here:

```
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
```

The variables here are only used to identify the order and display relevant information to the customer. IPN is used to actually 'complete' the order in our backend. So far so good.

However, when using a mobile device, PayPal will NOT POST back any data to the return_url whatsoever.

Some answers have suggested setting

```
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
```

This does nothing.

Has anyone found a way around this? We could rework the return_url for mobile devices, but the data we can send back is limited, so it's not ideal.

TIA

Comment: We never resolved this. In fact, we found that in about 1% of cases, even the desktop version failed to post back data. This caused all sorts of problems as you can imagine!

Comment: Is this problem restricted only to the sandbox environment? or is it on live too?

Comment: Related Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174585/paypal-post-payment-vars-not-present-on-mobile-checkout

Comment: @Jason - Yes, this was present on Live too

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by last paragraph which says that we could rework the return_url? Can you please explain that, as I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @DineshPrajapati - Sorry, this was quite a while ago now so I can't quite remember... We ended up changing our integration to use a 3rd party (Sagepay)

Answer (score 0):

It is related to the Safari postback bug. The root cause of the bug is the Negotiate authentication setting under IIS. You have to remove it and leave the NTLM authentication only. But it didn't resolved my problem, but hopefully yours.